# Build kernel for Ubuntu Server 18.04 running on Raspberry 3B+

Tags: server, kernel, raspberrypi

I've been trying to build a kernel for Ubuntu 18.04 running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ for two days now and I'm stuck. I need to build it from source 'cause I want the RT_PREEMPT patch, but for now I'm just trying to build a clean version.

I tried to compile version 4.19.72 from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.8.tar.xz by following the official guide for Raspbian and [this](https://www.get-edi.io/Real-Time-Linux-on-the-Raspberry-Pi/) blogpost:

For the config step I tried:

```
wget -O .config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/linux/rpi-4.19.y/arch/arm/configs/bcm2709_defconfig
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- olddefconfig
```

and I tryed to use the .config from /proc/config.gz on the pi running the official 18.04 Server image.

Then for compilation I used:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage modules dtbs
```

And for installation:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- INSTALL_MOD_PATH="root partition" modules_install
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/zImage "boot partition"/vmlinuz_test
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/*.dtb "boot partition"/fat32/
```

As there were no overlays I skipped that step.

At last I edited the `config.txt` on the "boot partition" to use the Pi bootloader:

```
kernel=vmlinuz_test
initramfs initrd.img followkernel
#device_tree_address=0x02000000
```

After this the pi doesn't boot anymore and I can't really debug the issue as I don't have a monitor and I can't find any changing logs on the card.

Can I use the same `initrd.img` as the original kernel? I can't find any in the compilation folder so I kept the same, but that might be a problem.

I really hope that someone can help, anyways thanks for reading this pretty big post.